# Quartz execute method not accessing other class or beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

Sorry if any mistake in writing , I had created spring boot application with  quartz scheduler, My issue is quartz execute method is not accessing outside class or beans it's returning null always and job get stop.

```
@Component
public class Sample1 implements ApplicationContextAware,ServletContextListener{
         private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;
         private static StdSchedulerFactory factory = null;
         private static Scheduler sch;

     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

          CONTEXT = context;
       }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
       try {
          sch=factory.getScheduler();
          sch.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        }
   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     contextDestroyed();
   }
}
```

This is a simple code to start quartz scheduler and it get started and job also gets triggered and start executing not in execute method

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class TempExecutionJob implements Job,InterruptableJob{
  @Override
     public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws 
                                                     JobExecutionException {
     String ss=OtherClass.val1;
     System.out.println(ss);

    }
  }
```

Here OtherClass is a simple java class which has one static variable val1 whose value is set on server startup but while executing job it always prints null and in debug mode on hover value is visible but in execution it takes null, i don't understand why this is happening , Please if some one can help

Comment: Having a public variable `val1` violates a class encapsulation. What is the purpose of it? And do you have any evidence that the "value is set on server startup"?

Comment: @Boris in another class for getting some values it is working properly, so value is set properly

Comment: If the value is set, then how come it's null?

Comment: @Boris yes that's the issue i am not getting it , even in debug mode on hovering that variable value is shown but when executing it prints null

Comment: How is `OtherClass` initialised and instantiated? And still why do you use a public variable?

Comment: OtherClass is a simple public class , and my variable is public static because i am reading it from properties file and it will available thru out the program so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180337/discussion-between-boris-and-user3458271).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest following advice offered by Boris in the chat. Once you move the property to application.yaml you should be able to get access to it after you initialize spring context within your job using `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`

Comment: it is not just related to one variable that i am not able to it is also other beans and classes are also not accessible , because quartz and spring works in different context and they are not aware of each other so for that the best solution i found is this [link](http://blog.btmatthews.com/?p=40)  which work forme